# TP4056 & resistor at VCC

Tags: batteries, charger

Could someone please explain me what is the 0.4Ω resistor at the Vcc pin (yellow color)? Why it is surrounded by a dashed rectangle? Should I add such kind of resistor when I design my circuit?

[image: TP4056 Typical Application]

Comment: Always add a link to the datasheet to make it easy for those trying to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you leave out the resistor and charge a battery with 1A (maximum current that the TP4056 can do) then the TP4056 will have to dissipate: 5.0 V - 4.0 V = 1.0 V * 1 A = 1 Watt (I'm assuming about 50% battery charge so 4.0 V). That's a lot for such a small SOP package and the TP4056 will get quite **hot**.

If it gets too hot it will lower the current but then your battery will charge slower.

This is where the 0.4 ohm resistor comes in, it will drop 1 A * 0.4 ohms = 0.4 V. That means the TP4056 will now only need to drop 0.6 V. At 1 A that means 0.4 W is dissipated by the resistor and " only" 0.6 W needs to be dissipated by the TP4056. This might be just low enough for it not to become too hot.

So if you are going to charge your battery with about 0.5 A to 1 A, then I would add the resistor.

If you're going to charge your battery with less than 0.5 A you can probably safely leave out the resistor.

Oh the dashed rectangle: it means that this resistor will get slightly hot and to cool it it is advised to keep other components out of the way and using somewhat larger copper areas on the PCB connecting to the resistor is advised as that helps to keep it cool.

Comment: When you say 5V you mean the input on the TP, right? Meaning that if I feed it with 6V (8V is the max), then the dissipated power will be much more. Ok... Lets assume 5V supply input then and battery at 2.7V exactly after the preconditioning. Does that mean that I will have (5V-2.7V) * 1A = 2.3W of power that will have to be dissipated by the TP? Isn't this much larger problem considering that a 0.6ohm resistor will only disipate 0.6W at 1Ampere? I haven't seen such resistor in other designs (eg the Chinese O3962A module).

Comment: When I say 5 V I mean the as indicated in the schematic so that's **not** the TP4056's Vcc pin but the 5 V line at the top side of the 0.4 ohm resistor. Sure if you use 6 V (or more) instead of 5 V then obviously the voltage drop needs to be even more. Resulting in more power dissipation. At Vbat = 2.7 V the TP4056 "knows" that the battery is depleted and **should not** be charged with the full current so it will charge with a smaller current until 2.9 V is reached. Indeed at 1 A that will make the TP4056 hot so it will limit the charging current.

Comment: *Isn't this much larger problem* It is not so much a problem because the TP4056 will limit the charge current such that it does not get too hot. But honestly, if you want to fast charge (at 1A) then the TP4056 isn't so suitable. Either use it at a much lower current (500 mA or less) and wait longer for a full charge **or** use a chip/module that can handle 1 A better.

Comment: I thought the TP is constant current - constant voltage. If what you are saying is true, then it either needs a heat-sink or it is wrongly advertised as 1A charger. I will have some tests tomorrow and observe it with a simple multi-meter and some digital thermometer to verify these. Thank you!

Comment: It **is** CC and CV **but** what is used (and at what current) depends on the state of the battery. And that's good because that is what Lithium based cells need. The TP4056 **can** handle 1 A **but** you need to limit it's power dissipation if you always want the full 1A. So yes, heat-sinking (just make sure the IC's pins are connected to large copper plates on the PCB), the series resistor and a lower supply voltage all help with that.