# Can a TP4056 Li-ion charging module charge a LI-ion cell at a reduced input voltage?

Tags: voltage, diodes, battery-charging

From [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393859/tp4056-resistor-at-vcc) answer I understand what the resistor between TP4056 ([found a link to this pdf](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf)) VCC and the power supply is used for.

I'm thinking to add a diode instead of it, because that will provide me with accidental polarity switch defense. If I use SS34, I shall have 0.5 V voltage drop.

The USB charging that I'm planing to use shall deliver from 4.75 V to 5.25 V. This means that TP4056 will receive at least 4.75 V - 0.5 V = 4.25 V, and I will not need to add the resistor that serves to drop the voltage close to the charging voltage, to avoid overheating. For me this diode is important, because I'm a hobbyist, not for current limitation, because I'm going to charge the cell with 130 mA (using 10 k resistor to pin PROG).

My question is: Will a TP4056 Li-ion charging module be able to charge the cell to its fixed limit for the IC of 4.2 V (as per the specs of TP4056), in the worst case, when supplied by 4.25 V?

The specification sheet claims that Vcc in range 4 V to 8 V is acceptable, but I do not understand how it will charge to 4.2 V from 4.0 V. Can you please comment on that as well?

Comment: See this, internal schematic https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497885/tp4056-charge-enable-and-battery-detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will TP4056 be able to charge the battery to its limit fixed for the IC of 4.2V (as per the specs of TP4056), in the worst case, when supplied by 4.25V?

Yes, but more slowly, due to the physics of the cell and the resistance of the pass transistor in the module. The cell will draw less current when a lower voltage is applied to the module. But charge it will.

> how it will charge to 4.2 V from 4 V I do not understand

It can't. With 4 at its input, it will charge the cell but not fully.